# Import with __init__.py on windows

Tags: python, django, django-views, python-import

Currently I have a directory that looks like this:

```
-test
  -functions
    -sub_func
      -add.py
      -__init__.py
    
    -__init__.py
    -main.py
```

I want to import add.py into main.py, and it works if I do `from sub_func import add` , but it comes with `pylint(import_error)` saying unable to import 'sub_func'. So I tried `from functions.sub_func import add` the pylint error is resolved, but when I run it, an error appears saying `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'functions'`

Is there a way I can import add.py while keeping the `__init__.py` files?

edit: I am using python3.9

edit2: So I didn't resolve the problem, but for some reasons, if I had `from sub_funct import add` in the provided `views.py` from django, it causes an error, calling that Module not found, but it works when I just python run it in the terminal.

Opposite happened when I used `from functions.sub_func import add`, running python in server didn't work, with the error message saying `no module named 'functions'`, but by running the server, the import seems to be working.

I am happy it's working, but I am very confused on why it works when I run the django server, but it doesn't work when I run it using python straight away, or the other way around.

Comment: Try `from sub_func import add`

Comment: @Sociopath It works that way, but I want to keep the ```__init__.py``` file, since this is just a quick directory created to represent my django project, and if I just import it like that, django doesn't like it

Comment: Try `from .sub_func import add`.

Answer (score 0):

you have to type in

```
from .sub_func import add
```

**or**

```
from .sub_func.add import *
```

Hope it worked :)